# Update error in MySql Column With Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple database with two columns - id and file_name. In file_name column I have mp3 filenames such as Summer of 69.mp3 . Now I want to rename 10 filenames with UPDATE statement. But what I have tried is updating only the last one file.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect ('host','user','pwd','database')
   or die ('Error connecting to database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbc,$query)
      or die ('Error Came');

echo '<form action=rename.php method=post>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$filename = $row['file_name'];
$fid = $row['id'];

echo '<input type="text" name="f[]" value="'.$row['file_name'].'" size="50"><br/><br/>';

}

echo '<input name="submit" type="submit" value="update"></form>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach ($_POST['f'] as $f ){

$query = "UPDATE files SET file_name ='$f' WHERE id='$fid'";
mysqli_query ($dbc,$query)
      or die ('Error Came');
}
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Any way out to fix this ?

Comment: Why do you have a SELECT at all???!?

Comment: Having a select column helps me getting those filenames rendered in my rename form.

Comment: You get the filenames from `$_POST['f']` then you must get fids from `$_POST` also like `$_POST['fileids']` and update a file name according to its file id.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$f=$_POST['f'];
foreach ($f as $key=>$value ){
$query = "UPDATE files SET file_name ='$value' WHERE id=$row[$key]";
mysqli_query ($dbc,$query)
      or die ('Error Came');
}
}
```

This may work for you

Comment: Thanx for helping out. But update Error is coming "Error came".

Answer (score 0):

Only last file is updating because $fid contains the id of last file.

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($i==0)
{$fid = $row['id'];$i++;}//now $fid contains the first file's id
$filename = $row['file_name'];


echo '<input type="text" name="f[]" value="'.$row['file_name'].'" size="50"><br/><br/>';

}
```

Now in the other part

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach ($_POST['f'] as $f ){

$query = "UPDATE files SET file_name ='$f' WHERE id='$fid'";
mysqli_query ($dbc,$query)
      or die ('Error Came');
$fid++;
}
}
```

Comment: Bro I tried your code. But now it is updating only the first file.

Comment: @AmitPal can you check whether the value of $fid is incrementing each time after the updating step?

Comment: No. It is only updating the first file.

Comment: can you echo the value of $fid. So that we can know whether it is incrementing after the upate statement

Comment: $fid is echoing same id for 10 different filenames if i put echo within while loop.

Comment: not in the while loop, echo it in the for each loop after execution of update query and incrementing of $fid

Comment: Yes it is echoing 10 ids.

Comment: Then it should update 10 files. isnt those are ids of the files?

Comment: No. The ids that are being echoed are not existing in database. Suppose I have ids 139 - 143 in database. But $fid is echoing 144-148.

Comment: Bro, then you modify the code so that $fid contains the id of first file before entering the foreach loop. then increment $fid after each update, so that it matches your fids in database

Comment: Yes bro I modified the code. Now its working fine. Thanks a lot bro for helping out. I have just removed the $i++; in the while loop as it is increasing the value one by one.

Comment: Sorry bro another problem is coming. The filenames are being updated reversely. e.g. If i update the first id then the last id is updated with that name.